# Ошибка Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, php7

У меня выходит вот такая вот ошибка возможно связано с переходом на php 7.4.14, раньше все работало

```
2021/01/23 06:57:50 [error] 2824#2824: *1983 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in 
/var/www/html/engine/classes/Main.class.php on line 110" while reading response header from upstream
```

Вот Main.class

```
$order = $this->order((int)$account->id);
```

Comment: `$account` у вас `null`

Answer (score 0):

Твой `$account` не объект , возможно там массив или null, если массив, используй `$account['id']`